# how to access raw data in Postman(Request section)?

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman, postman-testcase

So I want to print out the client Name and the client Email as string values through the Postman console, but when I call the method I get a the array but with undefined values.

```
const res = pm.response.json();
const req = pm.request.toJSON();
let user = [req.body.raw.clientName, req.body.raw.clientName];
console.log(user);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get request body raw using:

```
pm.request.body.raw
```

For example:

You have request body in postman:

```
{
    "foo": "bar"
}
```

You want to access value of `foo` in tab Tests:

```
const req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw)
console.log(req.foo);
```